# Leaflet Pan Event (moveend) is not working

Tags: leaflet, pan

I am trying to update two fields from database if map pan based on it longlat position. I am using the following code

```
map.on("moveend", function () {
    var cntLat = map.getCenter().lat;
    var cntLong = map.getCenter().lng;
    var zoomScale = map.getZoom();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",

        url: 'panevent.php?&zoom=' + zoomScale + '&getLat=' + cntLat + '&getLong=' + cntLong,
        success: function (result) {
            var JSONobject = JSON.parse(result);
            var title = JSONobject[0]["title"];
            var subtitle = JSONobject[0]["subtitle"];
            $("title").html(title);
            $("subtitle").html(subtitle);
        }});
});
```

Here is my HTML Block

```
<div class="currentLoc">
  <p id="title"></p>
  <p id="subtitle"></p>
</div>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

L.Map does fire `dragend`. You have to use `moveend`

`dragend` is for draggable [L.Marker](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#marker)

Comment: I also used `moveend` but no luck still. I have used `alert(title+subtitle);` to check. Its returning exact alert but the `<p></p>` field is not populating.